# Where can I define methods to be called on Tables?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

(I'm a complete beginner with Scala and Slick, so code review of any kind is appreciated)

I have the following `class` and Slick `Table` defined:

```
case class Foo(title: String, description: String, id: Int = 0)

class FooTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Foo](tag, "FOO") {

  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def title = column[String]("TITLE", O.NotNull)
  def description = column[String]("DESCRIPTION")

  def * = (title, description, id) <> (Foo.tupled, Foo.unapply)
}
```

I want to add a method which will return a `List` of `Foo`s which match a specified `title`. Something like this:

```
def findByTitle(title: String) = DB.withSession { implicit s: Session =>
  <FooTable TableQuery>.filter(_.title === title)
}
```

I'd then be able to use the method like this:

```
val foos = TableQuery[FooTable]
DB.withSession { implicit s: Session =>
  val anId = foos.findByTitle("bar")
}
```

How/where can I add a method which can act on a `TableQuery` for a particular `Table`? Is this even the correct way to be arranging my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
implicit class FooTableExtensions(q: Query[FooTable,Foo]){
  def findByTitle(t: String) = q.filter(_.title === t)
}

foos.findByTitle("Bar")
```

See Scala eXchange 2013 talk our website.

For pre-compiled queries it may be useful to have a DAO though, where you can cache the pre-compiled query. See Scala Days 2013 talk. Syntax changed since then though.  Check the manual for `Compiled`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Re: Scala Days 2013, did you mean the Slick vs ORM talk?

Comment: My architecture has evolved thanks to the advice from various sources about using a DAO. I'm now trying to deal with the same problem in a different environment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669616/where-to-put-my-database-access-methods-when-using-a-dao-with-slick-2-0. I'd appreciate your help if you have time!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to introduce a DAO (data access object), depending on your needs you could let the companion object of the `FooTable` class be the DAO which would let you call `FooTable.findByTitle()` from the rest of your codebase.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup on DAOs - I can see more than a few benefits to using them.

Comment: My architecture has evolved thanks to the advice from various sources about using a DAO. I'm now trying to deal with the same problem in a different environment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669616/where-to-put-my-database-access-methods-when-using-a-dao-with-slick-2-0. I'd appreciate your help if you have time!