# Where to put my database access methods when using a DAO with Slick 2.0?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0, play-slick

*(This question is based on a very similar [previous request for help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624151/where-can-i-define-methods-to-be-called-on-tables). With the introduction of a DAO and multiple database drivers, the same problem requires a different approach, and I hope warrants a new SO question.)*

I have a `class` and Slick `Table` defined like this:

```
import play.api.db.slick.Profile

case class Foo(title: String, description: String, id: Int = 0)

trait FooComponent extends Profile { this: Profile =>
  import profile.simple._

  class FooTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Foo](tag, "FOO") {

    def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def title = column[String]("TITLE", O.NotNull)
    def description = column[String]("DESCRIPTION")

    def * = (title, description, id) <> (Foo.tupled, Foo.unapply)
  }
}
```

And a data access object:

```
class DAO(override val profile: JdbcProfile) extends FooComponent with Profile {
  val foos = TableQuery[FooTable]
}

object current {
  val dao = new DAO(DB(play.api.Play.current).driver)
}
```

This is pretty awesome, because now I can add something like the following to my `application.conf`:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"

db.test.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.test.user="testuser"
db.test.password=""
db.test.url="jdbc:postgresql:testdb"
```

... and if I do the following in a Controller:

```
import models.current.dao._
import models.current.dao.profile.simple._
```

I have access to my `foos` `TableQuery`, and it automagically gets the driver and database url given for `db.default` in `application.conf`.

In a similar, but not-quite-as-nice way, I can do the following in my test `Specification`:

```
"test Foos" in new WithApplication() {
  val dao = new DAO(play.api.db.slick.DB("test").driver)
  import dao._ //import all our database Tables
  import dao.profile.simple._ //import specific database methods

  play.api.db.slick.DB("test").withSession { implicit s: Session =>
    println(s.conn.getMetaData.getURL)
    println(foos.list)
  }
```

However, what if I want to define a method which can act on a `TableQuery[Foo]`? Something like this:

```
def findByTitle(title: String) = foos.filter(_.id === id).list
```

---

**Problem**

What's the correct way of writing the `findByTitle` method, and where should I put it so that I can:

- Call it in a way such that it won't collide with a method of the same name which acts on `TableQuery[Bar]`. Coming from OO, I feel like I want to do something like `foos.findByTitle("someFoo")`, but if there's a better way of doing this functional-style, I'm open to suggestions.
- Call it from an application Controller such that the query will work with my `db.default` h2 driver, and from my test `Specification` so that it will work with my `db.test` postgres driver.

---

As an aside, if I can put this in my DAO:

```
object current {
  val dao = new DAO(DB(play.api.Play.current).driver)
}
```

and then `import models.dao.current._` anywhere I want to use this DAO, how can I extend the same form to the following:

```
object test {
  val dao = new DAO(play.api.db.slick.DB("test").driver)
}
```

If I try to do this, the compiler complains about not having `an implicit Application in scope`.

Comment: For anyone confused (like I was) about why my DAO doesn't contain the `Table` and has `class DAO(override val profile: JdbcProfile) extends FooComponent with Profile` instead of `class DAO(val driver: JdbcProfile)` like you might see in other examples, I'm using the play-slick plugin. Check out the differences between these two examples: [play-slick](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/samples/play-slick-cake-sample/app/models/DAO.scala) and [slick](https://github.com/slick/slick-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/examples/lifted/MultiDBExample.scala)...

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to read up in implicit conversion and implicit parameters in Scala. There are online Scala books available.

When you get an error message about a missing implicit it either means you ran into a failing type-check provided by a library preventing you from doing something wrong, but that's not the case here. Or you simply forgot to make the implicit available. There are two ways to make an implicit available. Either import it into the scope where you get the error message. Or basically defer the lookup to the callsite of your method. Not sure which one is the right one for play. You either need to import the implicit Application from play, or you need turn `val dao` into a method and request an implicit application in an implicit argument list `def dao(implicit app: Application) = ...`. You can alternatively turn test into a class and request it there.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the play slick plugin it will need a started play application to be able to call code that uses the DB access from that plugin, you can make sure to start a play app in your tests using `WithApplication` as described in the docs: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithSpecs2